# GLTF exporting animation (blender 2.79)

Tags: gltf

This code works for generating the model, and the gltf model performs properly in a gltf viewer. But the model doesn't animate and it's orientation is wrong when viewed through the phone camera on the webpage.

```
    <head>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
         <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://raw.githack.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/2.2.1/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
        <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;'>

            <a-marker-camera preset='custom' type='pattern' url='https://www.sblx.rf.gd/markertest.patt'></a-marker-camera>
            <a-entity gltf-model="https://www.sblx.rf.gd/boner.gltf"
            position="0 0 0"
            scale="1 1 1">
            </a-marker>
            <a-entity camera></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
 </html>
```

since it works properly at https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ maybe it has to do with the html code? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found out I needed to add a seperate component, called animation-mixer.

`<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v5.0.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>`

for anyone else in the future who might have this problem. Lots of useful parameters can be found here: https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders